# If I want to write and publish a book where I use C++ code for GPUs, what are the steps?

Tags: books, code

If I want to write and publish a book where I use my examples with C++ code that I have written  for specific GPUs, what are the steps? Is there an infringement, because I will base the examples to GPU code??

Comment: What sort of infringement are you worried about?

Comment: For instance, how possible it is to use code for not-open source famous GPUs? The same happens for famous FPGAs, where the code is not open source...

Comment: How is this related to academia?

Comment: Of course it has relation with academia, since the book will have code inside, and I am asking If this can cause me problems....

Comment: I don't understand your use of "code". When you say "not-open source GPUs": The GPU is a piece of hardware. There is no code involved, so there is nothing that could be "open source". So I'm confused about what you refer to.

Comment: When you want to make good use of a GPU, you write C/C++ that engages GPU processing on what you want to compute: either image processing or Machine Learning or DSP in general...And my question is what happens if someone want to use C/C++ code targeted on this specific hardware (GPU, FPGA, TPU,...) and put it in his/her book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manufacturers of GPUs do not sell you their product with a condition attached that you cannot publish code for them. In any case, this stipulation would probably not hold up in a court of law. Thus, providing code written by you for a patent and trademark protected GPU is not a violation of your purchasing agreement.

Comment: there are a variety of book using/showing proprietary codes (abaqus, comsol, matlab). OP: go to the library, grab a copy of this book and check what disclaimer they add (usually something like "the coe is provided as is, with no endorsment from the code publisher/manufacturer")